# bind_result($count); doesn't seem to work for this code

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't figure out why this won't work.  The database connects properly everything after the die staitment works if I remove it.  I get a count value of '' for all 4 but if I manually execute the command

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `models` WHERE `fair` LIKE '%,C,%'
```

I get `260` as the result.

Here is my code.

```
<?php 
require_once "includes/config.php";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATA);
if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);


//get list of fair options
$fairOptions=array(
    "C"=>"Center of gravity centered",
    "F"=>"Faces all same size",
    "T"=>"Same relationship with all other faces",
    "L"=>"Same friction on all faces"
);
$query="SELECT count(*) FROM `models` WHERE `fair` LIKE ?";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$test);
$stmt->bind_result($count);
foreach ($fairOptions as $key=>&$value) {
    $test="%,?,%";
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $key . "=>" . $count . "<Br>";
    $value="$value($count)";
}   
die();
```

Comment: @chris85 how did you get the code block for the sql statement to work.  every combination I tried of ` and \ didn't seem to work

Comment: You only had three spaces, just needed the fourth one.

Comment: Yah I deleted because the ` symbols kept disapearing

Comment: Hmm not sure about that. It worked for me as is. I removed the "\" on a second version. As for your question I'm not too familiar with `mysqli` but do you need to fetch for the bind_result to work?...hmm can't get formatting of this comment right though haha.

Comment: Once you have prepared a statement and bound a variable to the `?` **preferably one that actually exists** You then have to `execute` the prepared and bound statement before attempting to access any results. Otherwise all you have done is Removed the bottle cap, and pored the beer into a glass. You have not actually lifted it to your lips and taken a glorious gulp

Comment: @chris85 that's my mistake thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was executive but forgetting to fetch.  Interestingly if I put the '%,?,%' in the query and bind to $key it gives an error saying wrong number of peramiters

Comment: commas are field seperators, its probably getting confused.